# What does mean "see if it will help"?

Tags: meaning

I saw this sentence and I don't understand it

"see if it will help"

How can we see now if it will help in the future, it seems weird to me. May be in fact it is not see but" we'll see if it will help in the future" or better" we'll see if it helps ".First it helps then we can see this effect. This one seems more logical because you can't see the effect before the effect has happened

Comment: Colloquial expressions are not always logical. You can certainly say "We'll see if it helps", but people do also say "Let's see if it will help". "Let us see" has the sense "Let us make the experiment and see what happens".

Comment: What @KateBunting said. [Apparently,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=see+if+it+will+help%2Csee+if+it+helps&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20) we actually used to (slightly) *favour* the more verbose form until about 50 years ago (in *writing*, if not necessarily so much in *speech*). But since then we've massively shifted to preferring the shorter version.

Answer (score -1):

**See if it will help** the meaning of this - **you are offering** some solution or item to someone but **you are not sure** whether it is going to help anyway or not.